# CSS hover a video

Tags: css, iframe, filter

i have a problem, something missing,  with my css hover iframe of video, i want that when the cursor is hover and you are watching the video, effects disappears, if you see my code, hover effects is working, but when you hit play button video plays with the filter until you put your cursor hover.
I want to play video without effect, without the need to have the cursor on it.
thanks

```css
iframe { 
 
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  /* Firefox 3.5+, IE10 */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Fix for transition flickering */
}

iframe:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/209980107?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="540" height="260" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not have this capability.

You would need to use JavaScript to detect the play state and modify the styles from there (e.g. by toggling a class on the iframe).

Ordinarily, you cannot use JS to communicate between different sites through an iframe. [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) makes it possible providing the two sites co-operate but I suspect you are not in control of Vimeo's servers.

Vimeo might provide an API to allow you to detect play state. You should consult their documentation.